# My api post request is working in postman tool but it is showing error in the console of a browser?

Tags: node.js, api, postman

[This is postman tool and here post method is working fine here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xUmC.png)[I have attached here the screenshot of postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xUmC.png)

[In the console, it's showing error. Please help me to resolve this issue.][2[This is browser console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puLZi.png)

Answer (score 1):

In postman you are doing a post and in browser by default it's a GET

So the error says there is no endpoint that accepts a GET method.

If you change method to get in postman you should get same 404